# What is the correct way to pass a frame buffer from Swift to c++?

Tags: c++, macos, pointers, swift3

I've a c++ function (wrapped in obj-c files in Xcode):

```
int64_t* findEdges(int64_t* pixels, int width, int height);
```

that I'd like to call from Swift 3 and pass in a buffer full of picture data. After hunting around I'm calling it with:

```
var ptr = (NSData(data: imageRep.tiffRepresentation!).bytes).bindMemory(to: Int64.self, capacity: 4 * height * width).pointee

let processor = findEdges(&ptr, width, height)
```

But after accessing around 30 or 40 addresses in the c++ file I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash.

Is the problem that I'm passing unsafe pointers from Swift? What would be the correct call procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are at least some of the problems with this approach.  There may be more, since I don't know what exactly `findEdges()` input means and how that function finds the edges.

1. `NSData`'s `bytes` property is a raw pointer not bound to any type.  The call to `bindMemory` then indicates that the `NSData`'s content is to be treated as a buffer of `4 * height * width` of 8-byte integers, i.e. a buffer of `32 * height * width` bytes.  I haven't worked with the TIFF format lately, but I strongly suspect that a TIFF representation of an image of `width x height` size would contain a lot less bytes than that, so even if the buffer was successfully passed to `findEdges`, trying to treat it as much larger than it is would lead to an access violation.
2. The first 8 bytes of the image's TIFF representation are treated as an `Int64` and **copied** to the `ptr` variable, the address of which is then passed to `findEdges`, which treats it as the address of a buffer of `4 * height * width` `Int64` values.  However, only the 1st `Int64` in the buffer has anything to do with the image (it contains the first 8 bytes of its TIFF representation).  When `findEdges` accesses the 2nd `Int64` in the `pixels` array, it accesses memory having nothing to do with the image.  It may be lucky accessing a few more (garbage) `Int64` values, but will eventually try to access something it can't.

Solution depends on whether `pixels` required by `findEdges` contains the exact same byte sequence as the image's TIFF representation, or some transformation is required.  In other words, can we say that the first 8 bytes of the TIFF representation form the first element of the `pixels` `Int64` array, the 2nd 8 bytes - the 2nd element etc.

Assuming the buffer can be passed to the C++ function as is, here is a brief simplified example, which you can adapt to your needs.  Let's say the C++ function takes an array of `short`s with its size and looks like this:

```
void processBuffer(int16_t * buf, int count) {
...
}
```

We want to pass the contents of a `Data` from Swift as a buffer.  Here is how one might go about doing that:

```
var myData = ... 
myData.withUnsafeMutableBytes({(p: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16>) -> Void in
    processBuffer(p, Int32(myData.count / 2))
})
```

Please note that the buffer can be modified, not just read, in the C++ code, and the changes will be reflected in `myData`.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed answer. I'll take a look at your suggestion.